# Filling the missing index and filling its value with 0

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, fill

I have a pandas dataframe with a column value as index number

```
      Sales
140   100
142   200
145   300
```

I want to fill the missing index and also want to fill the value of missing index with 0

```
      Sales
140   100
141   0
142   200
143   0
144   0
145   300
```

I also want to fill missing values as the missing index number like

```
     Week_num
140   140
142   142
145   145

      Week_Num
140   140
141   141
142   142
143   143
144   144
145   145
```

I request you to help me how to code this out?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can using `reindex`

```
df.reindex(list(range(df.index.min(),df.index.max()+1)),fill_value=0)
Out[471]: 
     Sales
140    100
141      0
142    200
143      0
144      0
145    300
```

Comment: Thanks Wen for your fast response. Let me try it on my use case and mark the green tick :)

Comment: I prefer `df.reindex(range(df.index[0], df.index[-1] + 1), fill_value=0)` if the index is sorted. By the way I think this is a dupe.

Comment: Hi @coldspeed , this solution is also correct :) Yeah since this is dupe , I have assigned it to the new variable

Comment: Hi , What if I want to add the index value in the Sales column instead of 0? is there any way?

Comment: @AhamedMoosa do it with `df['Sales']=df.index.values`