# Converting Pandas Series to a List with indices preserved

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have this series:

```
ser = pd.Series(data=[11, 22, 33, 44, 88], index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 7])
ser
0    11
1    22
2    33
3    44
7    88
```

I want to convert it to a list so I do the following and result is:

```
ser.tolist()
result: [11, 22, 33, 44, 88]
```

However, what I want is a list where each element is inserted at the index it has in series:

```
[11, 22, 33, 44, 0, 0, 0, 88]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Related: [Fill missing index with 0's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50690963/filling-the-missing-index-and-filling-its-value-with-0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `reindex`

```
ser.reindex(range(ser.index.max()+1),fill_value=0).tolist()
Out[13]: [11, 22, 33, 44, 0, 0, 0, 88]
```

Comment: Very nice and concise!